# Elasticsearch dsl - large unique list of single column in python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I have a large Windows event log set that I am attempting to find unique listing of a users from a single column in a single event ID. This runs, but takes an extremely long time. How would you use python `Elasticsearch_dsl` and `Elasticsearch-py` to accomplish this?

```
    es = Elasticsearch([localhostmines], timeout=30)
    s = Search(using=es, index="logindex-*").filter('term', EventID="4624")

    users = set([])
    for hit in s.scan():
        users.add(hit.TargetUserName)

    print(users)
```

`TargetUserName` column contains stringed names, `EventID` column contains strings of event ids for windows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use a `terms` aggregations which will do exactly what you expect.

```
s = Search(using=es, index="logindex-*").filter('term', EventID="4624")
s.aggs.bucket('per_user', 'terms', field='TargetUserName')

response = s.execute()
for user in response.aggregations.per_user.buckets:
    print(user.key, user.doc_count)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, It looks as though it would work but I end up receiving a search_phase_execution_exception fielddata is disabled on text fields by default. and to set it to true. Do you know of another way around this as I do not have the ability to make this setting change lightly. Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: Can you share the mapping of your `TargetUserName` field? It's probably because it is an analyzed text field. Do you have a `keyword` sub-field in that field?

Comment: Unfortunately I can not, I am not the administrator of the device, I am only attempting to use the data in it for analysis. Would there be a different way to obtain the data?

Comment: What do you see if you run `curl -XGET localhost:9200/logindex-2017-01-04` ?

Comment: I got it to work via my tech for the device. It only displays 10 results as your code provides, I am assuming from a default setting. How could I change it to provide all results?

Comment: Cool, you need to add `size=100` (or any other number)  in the `s.aggs.bucket()` statement

Comment: Can I filter the usernames? I need to remove a specific set of usernames that contain a string. Should I do this before the agg in the search portion? Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Yes, it's better to do that with another filter, indeed.

Comment: I am attempting to create this filter and having problems, would you have a possible way to do this? Say I wanted to filter out all targetusernames that contain a # in it? Thanks again.

Comment: Depending on the mapping of your field (which we still don't know about), the `#` sign might not have been indexed. I think you should create a new question for this new issue, since it doesn't relate to this one.